# Worrying Invalid BSONObj errors when running db.stats() on a production MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, bson

Our production database (2.2.1 on 64bit debian) is throwing the following error below when we run db.stats():

```
> db.stats()
{
    "errmsg" : "exception: Invalid BSONObj size: 0 (0x00000000) first element: EOO",
    "code" : 10334,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

The following appears in our logs:

```
Fri Feb  1 16:28:46 [conn4081] Assertion: 10334:Invalid BSONObj size: 0 (0x00000000) first element: EOO
0xaf8c41 0xabedb9 0xabef3c 0x571fb7 0x6e880d 0x6f6411 0x6e8321 0x6e9cb0 0x6eab4c 0x830028 0x83376b 0x7b0b0d 0x7b20e2 0x56fe42 0xae6ed1 0x7fe7645378ba 0x7fe7638eb02d
 /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xaf8c41]
 /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11msgassertedEiPKc+0x99) [0xabedb9]
 /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod() [0xabef3c]
 /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod(_ZNK5mongo7BSONObj14_assertInvalidEv+0x497) [0x571fb7]
 /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod() [0x6e880d]
 /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo7DBStats3runERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRSsRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x321) [0x6f6411]
 /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12_execCommandEPNS_7CommandERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x51) [0x6e8321]
 /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11execCommandEPNS_7CommandERNS_6ClientEiPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0xe70) [0x6e9cb0]
 /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12_runCommandsEPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_11_BufBuilderINS_16TrivialAllocatorEEERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEbi+0x2ac) [0x6eab4c]
 /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11runCommandsEPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_5CurOpERNS_11_BufBuilderINS_16TrivialAllocatorEEERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEbi+0x38) [0x830028]
 /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo8runQueryERNS_7MessageERNS_12QueryMessageERNS_5CurOpES1_+0xc0b) [0x83376b]
 /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod() [0x7b0b0d]
 /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo16assembleResponseERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE+0x3a2) [0x7b20e2]
 /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo16MyMessageHandler7processERNS_7MessageEPNS_21AbstractMessagingPortEPNS_9LastErrorE+0x82) [0x56fe42]
 /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo3pms9threadRunEPNS_13MessagingPortE+0x411) [0xae6ed1]
 /lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x68ba) [0x7fe7645378ba]
 /lib/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fe7638eb02d]
```

We are getting quite concerned over this. Any ideas? All I can find on the net is old and non-conclusive.

Here is some more information:

```
> db.serverStatus()
{
    "host" : "hellboy",
    "version" : "2.2.1",
    "process" : "mongod",
    "pid" : 1432,
    "uptime" : 2672006,
    "uptimeMillis" : NumberLong("2672006216"),
    "uptimeEstimate" : 2626689,
    "localTime" : ISODate("2013-02-01T23:03:16.304Z"),
    "locks" : {
        "." : {
            "timeLockedMicros" : {
                "R" : NumberLong(333024517),
                "W" : NumberLong("54808066962")
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                "R" : NumberLong("30969573082"),
                "W" : NumberLong("4107434021")
            }
        },
        "admin" : {
            "timeLockedMicros" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(5942684),
                "w" : NumberLong(0)
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(48432),
                "w" : NumberLong(0)
            }
        },
        "local" : {
            "timeLockedMicros" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(1109128),
                "w" : NumberLong(0)
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(82283399),
                "w" : NumberLong(0)
            }
        },
        "gc" : {
            "timeLockedMicros" : {
                "r" : NumberLong("171460799918"),
                "w" : NumberLong("171384959016")
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                "r" : NumberLong("1816006512260"),
                "w" : NumberLong("3169374123999")
            }
        }
    },
    "globalLock" : {
        "totalTime" : NumberLong("2672006216000"),
        "lockTime" : NumberLong("54808066962"),
        "currentQueue" : {
            "total" : 0,
            "readers" : 0,
            "writers" : 0
        },
        "activeClients" : {
            "total" : 0,
            "readers" : 0,
            "writers" : 0
        }
    },
    "mem" : {
        "bits" : 64,
        "resident" : 4212,
        "virtual" : 443165,
        "supported" : true,
        "mapped" : 221237,
        "mappedWithJournal" : 442474
    },
    "connections" : {
        "current" : 364,
        "available" : 455
    },
    "extra_info" : {
        "note" : "fields vary by platform",
        "heap_usage_bytes" : 77840056,
        "page_faults" : 15189196
    },
    "indexCounters" : {
        "btree" : {
            "accesses" : 1490093267,
            "hits" : 1490093267,
            "misses" : 0,
            "resets" : 0,
            "missRatio" : 0
        }
    },
    "backgroundFlushing" : {
        "flushes" : 36144,
        "total_ms" : 614413596,
        "average_ms" : 16999.048140770254,
        "last_ms" : 352,
        "last_finished" : ISODate("2013-02-01T23:02:43.221Z")
    },
    "cursors" : {
        "totalOpen" : 5,
        "clientCursors_size" : 5,
        "timedOut" : 3,
        "totalNoTimeout" : 5
    },
    "network" : {
        "bytesIn" : 53731292608,
        "bytesOut" : NumberLong("2215346701908"),
        "numRequests" : 264535004
    },
    "opcounters" : {
        "insert" : 83515158,
        "query" : 141076950,
        "update" : 21415981,
        "delete" : 98,
        "getmore" : 685956,
        "command" : 18499441
    },
    "asserts" : {
        "regular" : 0,
        "warning" : 57,
        "msg" : 0,
        "user" : 0,
        "rollovers" : 0
    },
    "writeBacksQueued" : false,
    "dur" : {
        "commits" : 30,
        "journaledMB" : 0,
        "writeToDataFilesMB" : 0,
        "compression" : 0,
        "commitsInWriteLock" : 0,
        "earlyCommits" : 0,
        "timeMs" : {
            "dt" : 3074,
            "prepLogBuffer" : 0,
            "writeToJournal" : 0,
            "writeToDataFiles" : 0,
            "remapPrivateView" : 0
        }
    },
    "recordStats" : {
        "accessesNotInMemory" : 3070244,
        "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 1124345,
        "admin" : {
            "accessesNotInMemory" : 0,
            "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 0
        },
        "gc" : {
            "accessesNotInMemory" : 3070244,
            "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 1124345
        },
        "local" : {
            "accessesNotInMemory" : 0,
            "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 0
        }
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Did you try the steps suggested here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/HcAP54VutOo (for a potentially similar issue)? (Do you happen to have a 10gen support subscription?)

Comment: We don't yet have an oplog. This is the primary (and only) instance. We are in the process of raising replica sets but wanted to resolve this first. repairDatabase failed as the db seems to have shut down in the process.

Answer (score 5):

We have the same issue with our replica set and executing use local; `db.repairDatabase()` cleared the issue

Answer (score 4):

Eventually a

```
mongodump --repair --dbpath /data/db /path/to/dump
```

managed to generate a dump that we later used to recreate the database. The error went away. It meant some downtime, but now we can raise our replica sets without worrying about replicating a corrupt db.

Answer (score 3):

Are you running as a replica set?  If so, what happens when you run:

> use local
>   db.repairDatabase()

If you get a similar Invalid BSONObj error, you could have a corrupt oplog.

If that's the case you will want to re-build it:

1) For all other nodes in your replica set:
   - stop the node
   - delete the "local" directory
2) On your intended primary:
   - delete the "local" directory
   - start it
   - run rs.initiate()

Comment: Its not a replica set - its the primary. We were in the process of raising replica sets but noticed it before we started. 
I'm running repairDatabase at the moment.